# Leaving Sweden with a different passport?

Tags: passports, dual-nationality, sweden

Can I leave Sweden in August (by plane to Spain), showing my Argentinean valid passport even though I entered Sweden with a Spanish passport?

Or is it that they won't let me board the plane?

I have a route with a stopover in Denmark, or another one stopping in Netherlands. My Spanish passport is expired.

Comment: Does your Argentine passport have a Schengen visa?

Comment: Also, do you have ID you can use other than the Argentine passport?

Comment: No Schengen visa, I only use it to enter Argentina. I have been living in Sweden for the past 2 years, I have a Swedish id card from the Swedish Tax Agency, I don't think I can use it...

Comment: It looks as though your flights are intra-Schengen, not external, so you should only need ID, not a passport. If your Swedish ID card is accepted for airport security that may be better than showing a non-Schengen passport without a visa.

Comment: I think the Id is only valid for tax purposes... You can enter Schengen with the Argentinan passport without a visa.

Comment: I've only shown passport to airport security when leaving the US, never in the EU or the Schengen area. Before Corona your trip rarely would be a problem, in worst case Spain could have an extra border control but after some investigation they would accept your citizenship. Currently you can't enter Denmark and you probably can't go to Netherlands without a valid EU passport. What the rules are in August is unknown.

Comment: The Swedish national ID-card is the only recommended non-passport document for intra-Schengen travel, but is only issued to Swedish citizens.

Comment: Do you have a *Spanish* ID card?  If so, it is not correct that it is "only valid for tax purposes," and you should use it for your flight.  If not, what airline will you be using?

Comment: Also, does your Swedish tax ID card (or any other Swedish document) note that the basis of your residence in Sweden is your Spanish nationality?

Comment: Simple rule of thumb. **Schengen** === **Domestic**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This answer assumes that you are flying from Sweden to Spain without a connection outside the Schengen area.

Since Sweden and Spain are both in the Schengen area, as are Denmark and the Netherlands, you won't likely meet any immigration officers during your flight.  You only need to prove your identity to the airline.  Your Argentine passport should suffice.

Some airlines ask for proof of passengers' authorization to be in the Schengen area.  If your airline does so, they might accept the Argentine passport without looking for an entry stamp.  If they do look for an entry stamp, you'll have to prove that you are Spanish.  Whether the airline will accept an expired Spanish passport for that is anybody's guess.  You have to ask your airline.

If you do encounter any immigration officials, you will probably have to prove that you are Spanish.  They are more likely to accept the expired Spanish passport, because such a check would be "informal," but it's still not guaranteed.

If you have a Spanish national ID card, you should use that instead of any passport.  Otherwise, if you can acquire a Spanish national ID card or a new Spanish passport before your trip, you may want to do that.  If you cannot, however, there's probably a decent chance that you can do it with your Argentine passport and your expired Spanish passport (along with any other evidence of Spanish nationality that you can add to it).

Answer (score 4):

Phoog’s answer is correct for normal times. However, in August 2020 Europe might still have some kinds of Covid-19 type restrictions. As of May, if that is the case and which restrictions will be in place in August is anyone’s guess.

In normal times, you would only have to establish your identity with the airline at some point during check in or boarding for which the Argentinian passport should be enough – as would a Spanish national ID card (it is not the airline’s duty to check whether you are legally in the country based on stamps and visas afaik). An expired Spanish passport might also work. You would not encounter any immigration officers along the way and airport security would only need your boarding pass.

In Covid-19 times, any of the three countries you would be touching (Sweden, Denmark and Spain) may have installed temporary border controls conducted by police or immigration officers. If you do, your Argentinian passport will likely raise the wrong kind of questions such as ‘Where is the entry stamp?’, ‘How long have you been in Sweden?’ and ‘Where is your visa?’ You will want to avoid that at all costs. This only leaves the Spanish passport or a Spanish ID card.

As crossing an internal Schengen border still requires carrying a valid ID document (even if it doesn’t have to be shown), an expired Spanish passport *might* raise questions as it does not unambiguously show Spanish citizenship. However, officers might still exercise goodwill, especially if the passport is recently expired and since you are using it to travel back to Spain (that does not work for the return leg, though).

I personally would not feel safe using any of these almost options. There are still over two months until August which should be sufficient to renew your Spanish passport. In the absence of a Spanish ID card (and if it is not possible to acquire one in time), renewing the passport would be my method of choice.